# how to handle an unexpected popup in calabash-android

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, calabash-android

I am testing an app , which gives popup 1s or two times a day. and my script fails when this popup appears ... how to handle this kind of unexpected popup from the app.

Comment: Use this statement `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();`